# How to call a function in view by clicking a button in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to call the function ssl_verify from my html template . But it gives 404 error. Can anyone help me with this? Where i am wrong ?

```
#views.py
def ssl_verify( request , dns, port ):

if request.is_ajax():

    result = dns + port  
    return result

#urls.py
url(r'ssl_verify/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', views.ssl_verify,name='ssl_verify'),

#script in html 
function verify()
{

dns = document.getElementById("dns1").value;

port = document.getElementById("port1").value;

 $.post('ssl_verify/'+dns+'/'+port+'/', function (data) {

          alert (data) ;

            });
          }
```

Comment: The url in your post is probably wrong. See what is being called in your browser tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your urls.py must contain (replace the regexp line)

```
url(r'^ssl_verify/(?P<dns>[^/]+)/(?P<port>[^/]+)/$','views.check_ssl'),
```

or if you import:

```
from views import check_ssl

....

url(r'^ssl_verify/(?P<dns>[^/]+)/(?P<port>[^/]+)/$','check_ssl'),
```

and your views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def check_ssl( request , dns, port ):

    if request.is_ajax():
        message = str(dns)+str(port)
        return HttpResponse(message)

    else:
        return  HttpResponse('/faulthandler') # declare in urls if needed
```

Comment: how do you call the url in ajax call ? the way i am calling now says no url found . to your given url how to call it ? @dmitryro

Comment: $.get("http://yourdomain.com/ssl_verify/"+dns+"/"+port, function(data) {                             alert(data);  });